# Restoring Palm contacts

Tags: restore, contacts, palm

I want to restore my Palm contacts to my Palm T3 from my hard drive. I have the file saved is in .ABA format, CSV format and Vcal

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already done so, install the [Palm Desktop](http://kb.palm.com/wps/portal/kb/common/article/33529_en.html) program for your T3 (v4.1.4e)

Import the CSV file and then HOTSYNC your T3 with the Desktop program.

Comment: One of the unique features of PalmOS devices was the ability to effortlessly recover all your data after a device failure or upgrade. Assuming you hotsync'd regularly - as most did when Palm included cradles with the products. This ability is sadly lacking in the smart-phones that replaced Palm devices for most of us.

Comment: I would tend to disagree - assuming you have an always-on data connection, one's contacts / sms can easily be synced to the cloud. At least on an Android phone, thus obviating the need for one to manually "hotsync" each time changes to one's contacts were made in Palm.